# Setting mm_workspace with spaces in the filepath

Tags: json, mavensmate, sublime

I am setting up the Mavensmate Sublime plugin and need assistance setting the mm_workspace.  I need this variable set as /Users/Name 1/Google Drive/Salesforce/workspace

Here's what I currently have the syntax set as

"mm_workspace" : "/Users/Name 1/Google Drive/Salesforce/workspace",

However I get an error saying the variable is configured properly. I think its an issue with the spaces in the file but what am I doing wrong?

[image: error]

Comment: Have you tried escaping the space in the path name.  Like this "/Users/Name\ 1/Google\ Drive/Salesforce/workspace"

Comment: @sfdc_ninja yes, escaping the space in the path name results in an error message "Error trying to parse settings: Invalid escape Packages/MavensMate/mavensmate.sublime-settings:21:19"

Answer (score 1):

Because this is JSON, you need to escape your backslashes which you need to escape the spaces in your *nix filepath.  So it should be something like:

```
"/Users/Name\\ 1/Google\\ Drive/Salesforce/workspace"
```

Ugh! Right?

Comment: This is why I try to make my dev path without spaces....